# Как узнать причину последней перезагрузки Windows?

Tags: windows

Оставил включенным на ночь компьютер на Windows 10. Утром обнаружил, что он перезагружен (закрыты мои окна, время работы в диспетчере другое). Как узнать, почему компьютер перезагружался? Может в каких-то системных журналах есть об этом информация. Я живу не один и **хотелось бы убедиться, что это сделал не человек**.

Comment: в windows есть аудит и журнал событий. стоит посмотреть там. Но часто бывает, что там большинство событий выключено

Comment: Посмотрите, когда было последние обновление системы.

Comment: @ArchDemon, это смотрел. Там стоит User32 код действия 1074, то есть перезагружено пользователем или приложением

Comment: @Node_pro, подскажите, как можно посмотреть дату обновления драйверов Windows? С самими обновлениями я разобрался, но проблема в том, что за пару часов до произошедшей перезагрузки я сам перезагружал компьютер для установки обновлений. Хочу посмотреть точное время обновления драйверов из центра обновлений, но нигде не могу найти информацию

Comment: @ArchDemon оказывается это было системное обновление, о чем явно пишется в комментарии к событию в просмотре событий Windows. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Node_pro спасибо за помощь!